# A word for when I expect somebody to provide me something to continue doing my work

Tags: single-word-requests, rhetoric

What is the most suitable word (or a short simple expression) for the situation when I am blocked by another person/process and cannot continue my work until that process is done?

I suppose "expecting" or "awaiting" don't actually work because these don't reflect the possible negative outcome from waiting for too long, without taking responsibility for it by the person blocked.

Comment: Can you just say that you are blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple expression you may say:

I am **kept behind** in my work by another person against my own will.

Comment: In my situation, this expression is the best fit. Thank you!

Comment: "Kept behind" is fine but the "against my own will" sounds almost like you're being held hostage.  It's very negative, if an employer were to read that in an email, he might complain you were discrediting the company.

Comment: Hi, well I think that this is the meaning the OP was looking for as he specified 'without talking responsibility for it by the person blocked'.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> Baulked, blocked, stymied, obstructed, hindered, impeded, spinning one's wheels, treading water

or even

> Sabotaged, undermined, derailed, diverted

Answer (score 0):

- I am prevented from continuing my work because of X
- Until X, I am unable to continue my work.

Or, if you're not too worried assigning blame:

- I can't continue until X
- Because of X, I can't continue.

*In general*, although there are definitely exceptions, the fewer words you use, the more direct/harsh you'll sound.

Answer (score 0):

If you are  blocked from continuing due to awaiting output of a 3rd party your work is [**contingent**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contingent) on theirs.

> (contingent on/upon) Occurring or existing only if (certain circumstances) are the case; dependent on:
>   'his fees were contingent on the success of his search'

Answer (score -1):

The word you're looking for is *frustrated*.

You're feeling *frustrated* or *in a state of frustration* because you can't proceed with your work until the process is done. This is a *frustrating* situation for you.

> [**frustrated**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/frustrated): having a feeling or filled with frustration.
>
> [**frustration**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/frustration): the blocking or thwarting of an impulse, purpose, or action.

Alternately, consider *held up*.

*I'm now being [**held up**](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3940624?tstart=0) in my work trying (possibly in vain) to get to an alternative route*.

> [**hold up**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hold+up): cause to be slowed down or delayed.